# Not able to access Project to Project Reference in c# (path issue of dll)

Tags: c#, csproj, .net-7.0, project-reference

I have Project **M** (Main Project), **S**(shared project), and two class Libraries **A** and **B**. All projects have a new Build Configuration **Test.** **S** has project references of class libraries **A** and **B**. In **S** project Solution, these class libraries (**A** and **B**) are showing the correct bin folder path: "**...\..\bin\Test\net7.0\A.dll**" in dll Properties section. But, when I added **S** to the main Project **M**. the main project Solution, **S** is not showing the correct path of **A** and **B** dlls. It is showing Debug configuration build path: "**...\..\bin\Debug\net7.0\A.dll**". How can I fix it?

I have tried adding a PropertyGroup tag in csproj of A and B, just to change OutPath.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Test\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;Test</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Test\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;Test</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Having all projects in one sulution would make things easier as you could use proper ProjectReferences without having to adjust DLL paths.